# Let Maven create the `site` goal even if the tests fail

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am using Maven to test my eclipse project and call it with the following goals:

```
clean test site
```

This cleans, runs the tests and creates the HTML reports, but the latter only if all of the tests pass.

But when all of them pass, I have no reason to look at the test reports in HTML, I want to look at them if *not* all the tests pass to see what I have to fix!

A possible solution is splitting it up: In a second Maven launch configuration, I specify these goals:

```
site -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true
```

Then I have to run the first goal to test and the second goal if the first one fails. But that is just annoying.

Comment: why not run the tests through eclipse directly?

Comment: I have resources for the test that have to be at the `target/test-classes` directory for testing. But since I often modify these files, I have to run the tests via Maven to make sure the test resources get updated.